# Counting rows after splitting df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I had to break df into 20 equal groups (not really fully equal, there are 6076 rows). Now I need to create new df with column where each cell equal to count of rows in each group. For example, I have 20 groups with 304 rows, so I need column 'pool_size' looking like:
304 in first row, 304 in a second row, 304 in a third row....etc.

In order to break df I used:

```
>>> df_split = np.array_split(df, 20)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the questions, but you could try adding the column 'pool_size' with value equal to 304 for each row by:

```
    df["pool_size"] = 304
```

Edit:
After splitting the dataframe via np.array_split you have a list of dataframes so you can just iterate through the list and check each rows size via *.shape*. Then you can update that df via the code above. It should look something like this, but I haven't checked it.

```
    for df_ in df_split:
        df_["pool_size"] = df_.shape[1]
```

Comment: I'd love to do this, however one of groups has more rows, I am not sure which one))) Because total number of rows in original df is 6076... Actually I am not sure how many rows there are exactly, but I think that if I will not be able to find another solution, I will just check each group, and will do exactly what you suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Oh okay, since each row is not of the same length you can loop through the outer array and check the length of each inner array while changing the pool_size column. 

You can use *nditer* to loop through the array and then check each arrays size using *.size* or *.shape*. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pd.DataFrame([df.shape[0] for df in df_split], columns=['pool_size'])
```

Result:

```
    pool_size
0          16
1          16
2          16
3          16
4          15
5          15
6          15
7          15
8          15
9          15
10         15
11         15
12         15
13         15
14         15
15         15
16         15
17         15
18         15
19         15
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding, but can't you use:

```
df_split.shape[0] #for length/row numbers in DF
```

(or df_split.shape[1] for width)

Comment: Thank you! there are 20 groups) this one successfully counts the whole df or one group in split df, but not for each group unfortunately